# How do I $match for a specific list of keys and values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

this is my first question on SO and I couldn't find a real good answer for this, but forgive me if this is a repeat to another question asked.

I'm trying to do an aggregate on specific key value pairs, and want to narrow it down as much as possible in the $match pipe.

For example, say for the $match pipe I wanted to query for the following (using placeholder data, real dataset is different, keys and values):

```
{"name": "Michael Jordan", "sport": "Basketball"},
{"name": "Barry Bonds", "sport": "Baseball"},
{"name": "Wayne Rooney", "sport": "Soccer"},
{"name": "Deion Sanders", "sport": "Football"},
{"name": "Usain Bolt", "sport": "Track and Field"}
```

There could be 20-100 specific things I want to query for.

#### **What would be the best way to design the $match to query for these five?**

My first instinct would have been:

```
KeywordDailySentiment.aggregate(
       [
           {$match: {
                 $or: [
                    {"name": "Michael Jordan", "sport": "Basketball"},
                    {"name": "Barry Bonds", "sport": "Baseball"},
                    {"name": "Wayne Rooney", "sport": "Soccer"},
                    {"name": "Deion Sanders", "sport": "Football"},
                    {"name": "Usain Bolt", "sport": "Track and Field"}
                 ]
              }
             }
        ]
)
```

But as you can see, this looks terribad, and it doesn't work.

For sake of example, I would be running an aggregate like:

```
KeywordDailySentiment.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        /* Insert answer here for help, 
                        currently I am just making two arrays with 
                        all the players and sports and $matching with 
                        a couple of $in statements, probably not 
                        the best way

                        "dimensions.player": {$in: playerArray},
                        "dimensions.sport": {$in: sportArray},

                        */


                        "dimensions.stream": query["dimensions.stream"],
                        "date": {$gte: ago.toDate(), $lt: query.date.toDate()}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        "sentiment": "$dimensions.sentiment",
                        "player": "$dimensions.player",
                        "sport": "$dimensions.sport"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            sentiment: "$sentiment",
                            player: "$player",
                            sport: "$sport"
                        },
                        value: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
    ]
)
```

Comment: should the query match  `{"name": "Barry Bonds", "sport": "Soccer}`?

Comment: no, just "baseball", just the keys and values as is.